# How to improve wiring a breadboard?

Tags: wires

just saw this tweet and was interested what wires are used there:

https://twitter.com/EngineersGarage/status/448014811280842752/photo/1

[image]

The wiring Looks cleaner than the setup I currently have with "normal" wires.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the wire itself is perfectly normal. It looks like he's simply soldered right-angled header pins onto the ends. That way, the wires can lie flat on the breadboard instead of being bent over for connections, meaning the whole thing is lower-profile and a little easier to route neatly.

It also has the advantage that they will probably survive far more insertions/removals. With that said, it brings the disadvantage that it exposes the contacts more above the surface of the board, which could increase the risk of accidental connections (short circuits and such like).

Comment: thanks - indeed that was the explanation I was looking for. the wires I use quickly get harder to use, and These right-angle Header pins look helpful. any other advice on maybe special out of the shelve wires that help wiring a Project?

Comment: Various places sell packs of pre-cut and pre-bent wire specifically for breadboard prototyping. I find it's not really worth the price though. Fairly standard solid core wire is usually sufficient. Just make sure to use suitable lengths, and try to route things in straight lines (rather than sprawling all over the place!).

Answer (score 1):

Using good wires helps to build clean breadboard setups. I also found that it greatly helps to wire vertically only and to use the breadboard for horizontal connections. If you look at my picture, wires are always vertical. This is easy to achieve when you work with buses like I²C. As you can see, I also used horizontal lines from another breadboard as you can use these like Lego bricks, though you need to cut the adhesive tape in the back. For the wires, I used standard Solderless Breadboard Jumper Cable Wire that you can buy almost everywhere online.

You can also check other pictures on my blog: http://ouilogique.com/horloge_cycles_ultradiens/

[image]